# Why testing app in iphone WORKS with AppStore provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

To prepare to submit my app to the appstore i changed the provisioning profile from the developer one to the one i created for the appstore. Then i just made a distribution build , the app  get i stalled and everything works ... isn't it supposed to be possible to install the app only on developers devices (with all the complicated stuff of authorized devices, etc ... ) ? Or it is possible just because my iphone is jailbroken ? Or i did something wrong ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal devices only allow apps from the AppStore to be installed (or signed with a developer profile). If your iPhone is jailbroken, those security measures have been removed in order to install custom apps (from Cydia etc.). This is most probably the reason why you can install your app even though it has been signed with a distribution profile.

But hey, just to be sure, why not try it out on a non-jailbroken device too? If it doesn't work there, you can be pretty sure that that is the reason it works.

Comment: If i have a not jailbroken iphone, i wouldn't ask the question ^^ :D